# PyQt5 -> Closing Childwindow wont work

Tags: python, inheritance, exit, pyqt5

I'm fighting with some strange behavior of my code. Im using PyQt5 to create a GUI and the Subwindows wont close after i clicked the Button that should close the window. To be more precisely: I have a Button that is forwarding some data to the Core, and the Window should not contain an exit Button. The user just types in his input, clicks the button and the window should be closed.

Source from the mainwindow:

```
self.charCreationWindow = charcreation.CharCreation()
```

Code of the function that is "opening" the window:

```
    def newChar(self):
    self.charCreationWindow.exec()
    return
```

And finally the codeparts from the Pythonfile that defines the new window:

```
class Creation(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
.
.
.
.

 self.buttonCharCreationApply.clicked.connect(self.createChar)

 self.retranslateUi(Form)
.
.
.
.
def createChar(self):
.
.
.
        else:

        try:
            cursor.execute(sqlChar, charData)
            cursor.execute(sqlMisc, miscData)
            connection.commit()
            self.exit()
            self.errorDetectet("a message")



        except:
            Creation.errorDetectet("a message")
            self.exit()
        return
```

(Same file, new class:)

```
class CharCreation(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Creation()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Just to prevent misunderstanding: "Char" in that case is not meant like the char = 'a', its a questlog for a RPG.

I tried many things, calling "self.close", "self.exit" ... from the createChar function but nothing worked. self.close for example doesnt return any error, but nothing happens.

I'm at a point where i think that the solution might be pretty obvious, but i have no clue what to do next.

"errorDetectet" is just a QMessageBox that i use to inform the user about several steps. It does not containg any buttons, except "OK" (which closes the QMessageBox).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you putting all the program logic inside the UI class? It should go in the `CharCreation` class. Then calling `self.exit()` and such like would make sense.

Comment: This is a refreshing point of view. Thanks. I guess i stared too long at my code to be efficient in any way. I'll try as you said and keep you updated.